# Is there a widget for "friends using this app"

Tags: facebook, widget, facebook-widgets

Let's say a user is visiting my app website for the first time, so I don't know his/her Facebook uid, yet.

Does Facebook provide a widget similar to Like widget that lists **Facebook friends of that user using my app** (just like it shows his/her friends Liked that page in Like widget in an `iframe`)?

I remember such a thing however I couldn't find anything similar. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Facepile. Use it with an app_id, and it'll show the users's connected friends.

Here's the docs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/

Comment: Given that "Facepile" is now deprecated, I wonder if there is another way?